# Bind built-in method in React constructor

Tags: reactjs

Shall I do `.bind(this)` for built in React methods?

```
this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this)
this.componentWillUnmount = this.componentWillUnmount.bind(this)
```

Comment: You don't need, but a good question would be, `Why I don't need to do .bind(this) in the built-in methods`? That would be cool to know

Comment: These are the lifecycle methods comes with `import React from 'react'` package. We usually bind `this` to custom functions which are declared in `this` context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need.

These methods are already implemented by React and `this` will be the `this` of your class, not the function.